# Quickest way to compare local gem versions to what's 'out there'?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, rvm

I can't seem to remember this...  what's the easiest way to list all gems in my current gemset that need to (could) be upgraded to a newer version?  ...and ideally see any associated notes on what's change/new with the updated version?

**gem list** shows what I have locally and **gem list -r** shows me everything tracked up in the gem world. but i'm really only interested in seeing what, if anything, has changed with my current gems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's **gem outdated**. You can also do **gem help commands** to get a list of all gem commands if that's what you were looking for.